# delete row number in dictionary format from pandas dataframe column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

please help me with the following conversion please. So I have a pandas dataframe in the following format:

| id | location |
| --- | --- |
| { "0": "5", | "0": "Charlotte, North Carolina", |
| "1": "5", | "1": "N/A", |
| "2": "5", | "2": "Portland, Oregon", |
| "3": "5", | "3": "Jonesborough, Tennessee", |
| "4": "5", | "4": "Rockville, Indiana", |
| "5": "5",} | "5": "Dallas, Texas", |

and would like to convert this into the following format:

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| "5" | "Charlotte, North Carolina" |
| "5" | "N/A" |
| "5" | "Portland, Oregon" |
| "5" | "Jonesborough, Tennessee" |
| "5" | "Rockville, Indiana" |
| "5" | "Dallas, Texas" |

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame([['{ "0": "5",', '"0": "Charlotte, North Carolina",'], ['"1": "5",','"1": "N/A",']], columns=['id', 'location'])

#using regex to extract int values and selecting second int
df['id'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r'\d+', x)[1])

#Split the string with : and select second value. And remove comma
df['location'] = df['location'].apply(lambda x: x.split(':')[1][:-1])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  id                      location
0  5   "Charlotte, North Carolina"
1  5                         "N/A"
```